# Paypal IPN Simulator always returns INVALID response

Tags: php, paypal

I login to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ and input the url to my IPN listener, choose WebAccept and click "Send IPN".

The response is always **INVALID** no matter what I do! any idea why?

Here is the listener code:

```
<?php

    // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
    // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
    // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
    define("DEBUG", 1);
    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
    define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
    // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
    if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }
    // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
    // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
    // This is mandatory for some environments.
    //$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
        {
        if(DEBUG == true) { 
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    } else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
    $res = trim(end($tokens));
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process payment and mark item as paid.
        // assign posted variables to local variables
        //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
        // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    }
?>
```

Original code was taken from https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

`ipn.log` reads:

```
[2016-06-05 13:47 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 978
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun+Jun+05+2016+16%3A29%3A54+GMT+0300+%28%25u05E9%25u05E2%25u05D5%25u05DF+%25u05E7%25u05D9%25u05E5+%25u05D9%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05E9%25u05DC%25u05D9%25u05DD%29&payment_status=Pending&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=9.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=472771233&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=A17KMNpbM60OOCEIZz80EaMjjPqSAnUx3aCCkgB0A1bTiKC9g177Wos.
[2016-06-05 13:47 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2016 13:47:10 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=tlt2snjwLjVA4KM800GfFI7CuI8DwIePgXEB-XqiNjGzSE7uCOaa8AbpoiMOtjxHquk20x22R7upbBT9zlcHhoWo7Eg8VlXYI55Vpn8hLcjXWZJjulYxgQXpEG88cD8iI56pqto5AA0wj0s5nNjasazfAOsu7IFgETnBBkNFu9tDlvkgvSr0PW8nw1EqZe6uE59MwzSK3cstRnhc1aZEzvWAl8v_T4mTxojpeD9x7etCS7plKgKgzqeifM4fYQ03BWElzH7kFTl5v16PJDendcT5lA8bCIMUP890aFUOGax94KKkPRNUpqxx9HjXGjtqbFU_FgG7qMpyLc-ewaQyLkCfCmQdbhegqnS3YnQY1J6UHM06qTH-Fqr2Cso2Gm1qOczOFBnlZDfeai9M99zl11qB4OA0_ysecKM2s-YqXUrSQScOm52I0RSvc8i; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Wed, 03-Jun-2026 13:47:10 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Tue, 05-Jun-2018 13:47:10 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1465134430396449; path=/; expires=Tue, 29-May-46 13:47:10 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: c28115aa5c466
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1580029015%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Sun, 05 Jun 2016 14:17:10 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2016-06-05 13:47 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun+Jun+05+2016+16%3A29%3A54+GMT+0300+%28%25u05E9%25u05E2%25u05D5%25u05DF+%25u05E7%25u05D9%25u05E5+%25u05D9%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05E9%25u05DC%25u05D9%25u05DD%29&payment_status=Pending&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=9.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=472771233&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=A17KMNpbM60OOCEIZz80EaMjjPqSAnUx3aCCkgB0A1bTiKC9g177Wos.
```

Comment: Not sure about debugging using `error_log` - Can you comment that line and try again?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work... Which one are you referring? there are quite a few... :)

Comment: The one on the `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {` part (Or just set DEBUG = 0)

Comment: Oh wait, I think i've misread, reading the question again :| ...

Comment: you have asked this one before... as written then try using `===` with `strcmp()`

Comment: you are sure you get response from curl?

Comment: @PeterDarmis I have tried using `===` even though I don't see any `type` issues here. How can I find out if I get a response from cURL?

Comment: @AlonEitan If I set `DEBUG = 0` I have no way of telling if my response is valid or invalid.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote that I need to read it again. The only thing I don't see is that maybe you need to enable `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);` and point to the ssl certificate? I'm not sure though

Comment: I'm using `http` protocol, is that a problem?

Comment: It's `https` so perhaps changing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` will make it work somehow

Comment: @AlonEitan that could definitely be the culprit hehe, I've changed both `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `0` just to be sure, same result.

Comment: [Read this](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/) They say you must use SSL, so try download the relevant .pem from [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1516) and implement it in your code

Comment: @odedta `var_dump($res);` right after where `$res` is defined is fine to check if you have response from curl

Comment: @odelta based on your curl ssl configuration you need to set up this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO..)` properly. Check this tutorial http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/. I think that in your case if you use sandbox Paypal that you need to grab the SSL from that url for your test to work. I hope that this example will be helpful enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I am actually trying NOT to use SSL...

Comment: Paypal is ridiculous with their services, I just create a donate button from the sandbox page and it only works if I actually click it and being redirected to paypal sandbox to donate, otherwise the simulator does not work under any settings that i've tried... useless! thanks for trying to help guys... :/